# jquery attr() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just playing with the basics but I can't seem to get `$('p').attr({color:red});`  work.
I also tried using `$('p').attr(color,red);`  but that didn't work either.Please help,here is the whole code btw:http://www.codecademy.com/pyAce14978/codebits/SKByZJ/edit

Comment: Color is not an attribute of a paragraph tag..

Answer (score 6):

```
 $('p').css({
      color: 'red'
 });
```

or

```
 $('p').attr({
     'style' : 'color:red;'
 });
```

Comment: @roberskine-thanks,can you also clear me when to use '' and when not,like you wrote 'style' : 'color:red;' and not style:'color:red'

Comment: attr style is messy as it will overwrite any other inline styles you have

Answer (score 2):

Use css not attr Function instead

Comment: ...for example (please post a code example)

Answer (score 2):

That's because color is not an attribute of P. You need to change the CSS of P, not the "color attribute"

```
$('p').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0, 1];
e.style.color = "red";
```

Comment: Sorry, wrong code, try this pure javascript.

Comment: You may also want to look up the .setAttribute() function.

Comment: OP is experimenting with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You better use css `$('p').css('color', 'red');`